# 1960s or 1970s children's sci-fi about several teenagers exploring (or lost on) an alien planet?

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read this in grade school in the late 1970s/early 1980s.  I believe the cover may have been in blue and white with an alien landscape.  I recall the protagonists traveling in a moon-buggy r.v. of sorts.  In a weird twist at the end, they discovered the energy bars they regularly ate had been suppressing their growth or their libidos or something like that.  (Not in an adult way -- just preventing young boy/girl interest).

Comment: It could also be the same as this one:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33141/80s-book-about-kids-stranded-on-a-planet

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242583/book-about-ai-called-angels-who-look-after-a-child-left-alone-on-a-spaceship (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably *But We Are Not of Earth*, also asked about ['80s book about kids stranded on a planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33141/80s-book-about-kids-stranded-on-a-planet?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Story with student test to find a new world and bring back navigation data, teacher tried to persuade students to go native](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157009/story-with-student-test-to-find-a-new-world-and-bring-back-navigation-data-teac?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The details in this question are rather thin, but the key element (food bars that suppress romantic interest) is present, and the book definitely had a buggy for travelling around on the planet that the kids end up on.  The 1984 publication date also fits.

Comment: Good catch! Maybe Derick will one day return...

Comment: It's funny.  The apparently most distinctive feature of this book (having come up in all three questions searching for it) is not something that I really remember, actually.  I remember the characters wondering about what kept them from "pairing up" back at home, but I don't actually remember the part where they figured out it was the food bars.

Comment: And one day I did return.  I totally forgot posting this.  6 years later, I was thinking about that book again, Googled it, and discovered my own inquiry.  Ha!  I think you found the book.  Thanks!

Comment: @Derick You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark you see next to it.

Comment: Perhaps in another six years.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of food suppressing puberty makes me immediately think of [Earthsearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsearch) which was a radio series - but it did have a novelisation according to wikipedia. I don't specifically remember a moon buggy but they certainly went to the moon amongst other places and travelled around in a few different modes of transport.