YA short story about young people who crash land their space ship. They learn that adults had blocked their puberty
Basically looking for what is described in the title. Kids crash their ship and start living off the land without their normal rations, and they start feeling things like normal kids. I read it in a reading textbook but it was a textbook that was a sample from a publisher and not adopted by the school, because it was sort of subversive. I read it maybe in the mid to late '80s.

The novelization of Earthsearch had the puberty blockers.

This sounds like it could have been an excerpt from But We are Not of Earth (1981) by Jean E. Karl, which has come up a few times here previously.

Four students from Meniscus F on a mission to the far-away Sector 22 delight in the habitable but uninhabited planet they discover until they realize their pod mentor has plans he has not shared with them.

If the Internet Archive is up, the full novel is available there.

If accepted (you can click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to do so, as per the [tour]), it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157009/story-with-student-test-to-find-a-new-world-and-bring-back-navigation-data-teac?noredirect=1&lq=1
